# What requirement do I have to add while using from kivy.lang import Builder

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

No problems with packaging the app, but the app crashes once I open it. Is it because of the requirements?

I'm using the builder module from kivy.lang and some other modules such as get_color_from_hex, kivy.core.window.

I'd like to know if I have to add some more requirements in the buildozer file

This app is unfinished, but I'm pretty sure that those are all the modules that I'll need for my work, all it needs is a little work on the button actions.

The python code:

````
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

#Color a los widgets
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

#Color de fondo
from kivy.core.window import Window
#Definir color de fondo
Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex(("#3737C4"))


#from kivy.app import App
import kivy
kivy.require ('1.11.0')



code = """
<LeButton@Button>:
    text: ""
    on_press: app.escritura(str(self.text))  
    background_color: ("#656599")
    background_normal: ""
    font_size: '45sp'


BoxLayout:
    spacing: 20
    padding: 20
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput: 
        size_hint_y: .4
        text:""
        id: lb
        font_size: '45sp'


    GridLayout:
        spacing: 10
        cols: 4
        
        LeButton:
            text: "1"

        LeButton:
            text: "2"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "3"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "+"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "4"

        LeButton:
            text: "5"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "6"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "-"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "7"

        LeButton:
            text: "8"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "9"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "/"
        
        LeButton:
            text: ""

        LeButton:
            text: "0"
        
        LeButton:
            text: "="
        
        LeButton:
            text: "*"
        
        
"""

class AptitudeApp(App):
    Le_cuenta = ""
    
    def build (self):
        return Builder.load_string(code)
 
    def rut(self):
        
        self.root.ids.lb.text = "" 
    
    
    def escritura(self,text):
        
        if(text == ""):
            AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta = AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta[:(len(AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta))-1]


        if (text != "="):
            pass
        
        AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta += text 

        self.root.ids.lb.text = AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta

        print(AptitudeApp.Le_cuenta)
        
                
                

        
      
  

AptitudeApp().run() ```
````

Comment: With your android phone attached to your computer (with USB cable) run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. Then look at the `my_log.txt` for hints about what is going wrong.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks a lot